# Failed to compile - property does not exist on type Window

Tags: typescript

Augmenting window object fails to compile with typescript 3.5.3.

Before upgrading typescript, it had worked.

```
// somescript.ts
declare global {
  /* tslint:disable */
  type Window = {
    _TEST_PROP?: any
  }
  /* tslint:enable */
}

//someOtherScript.ts
window._TEST_PROP = {
 foo: 'bar'
}
```

Error: Property '_TEST_PROP' does not exist on type 'Window'.

I expect it not to fail compilation, as it had already worked before

Comment: What version are you upgrading from .. tried all the version is the playground, this never worked, type aliases don't merge. You need an interface ..

Comment: 2.1 I believe...could it be a case of a new plugin was added which also augments the window object (where it hadn't before) and in that case, it's correctly overriding it considering type aliases don't merge?

Or it just should never have worked in the first place and the compiler wasn't picking it up?

Comment: TS does not have plugins, unless you had a custom TS version. And I would expect that to error with duplicated identifier ..

Comment: I meant a new npm module, but yeah, still in that case I would have expected a duplicate identifier error too...hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this ever worked without errors, i expect it did not. Type aliases don't merge, interfaces do. `Window` is an interface, so you can augment it.

```
// somescript.ts
declare global {
  interface Window {
    _TEST_PROP?: any
  }
}

//someOtherScript.ts
window._TEST_PROP = {
 foo: 'bar'
}
```

Comment: Hmmm it definitely _has_ compiled before, no idea how though if you've never been able to merge type aliases.

Is this documented somewhere? I'm interested to see if there are any other pitfalls like this I can avoid
Thanks though :)